# media query breakout does not match

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using bootstrap v4 to arrange my grid.

The `lg` option is defined as 1200px, however I see the style is still applied even at around 1000px.

The Chrome DevTool shows the css rule (and makes it disappear when I get below ~1072px).

[image]

How come the media query rule does not match the size that Chrome Dev Tools detects?

Comment: Strange!! Has it got something to do with the page zoom? I guess not,

Comment: @GibinEalias I think you are onto something!!! I just reliazed that indeed my zoom was not set as "actual size"!

Comment: :) Glad that it helped. I will comment that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was caused due to the page zoom level not set to 100%.